# Merging three time series in R

Tags: r

```
library(qrmdata)
library(xts)
library(dplyr)

#load the data
data("EUR_USD")
data("SP500_const")
data("EURSTX_const")

#select stock and period
walmart <- data.frame(nr = SP500_const['2005-05-20/2015-05-19',"WMT"])
danone <- data.frame(nr = EURSTX_const['2005-05-20/2015-05-19',"BN.PA"])
exrate <- data.frame(nr = EUR_USD['2005-05-20/2015-05-19',])

#omit 'NA' entries
walmart <- na.omit(walmart)
danone <- na.omit(danone)
exrate <- na.omit(exrate)
```

I want to merge the three time series walmart, danone and exrate into one time series, but I only want those days in it for which I have data in all three time series.

I tried to merge danone and walmart first using

```
z <- merge(danone,walmart, join='inner')
```

which should merge danone and walmart (only using the days for which I have data from both danone and walmart) but it doesn't give me the output I described above

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner_join` from `dplyr` library

```
walmart$date<-rownames(walmart)
danone$date<-rownames(danone)
exrate$date<-rownames(exrate)

a<-inner_join(inner_join(walmart, danone,by = "date" ), exrate, by = "date")

> head(a)
    WMT       date   BN.PA EUR.USD
1 37.52 2005-05-20 24.8986  1.2561
2 38.05 2005-05-23 25.0496  1.2585
3 37.89 2005-05-24 25.1000  1.2586
4 37.61 2005-05-25 25.0832  1.2605
5 37.62 2005-05-26 25.3013  1.2513
6 37.59 2005-05-27 25.2006  1.2580
```